# Addressing list items in maven expressions

Tags: list, maven, collections, properties, expression

How can I address a list item in maven expression?

For instance in following snippet:

```xml
<configuration>
  <animals>
    <animal>cat</animal>
    <animal>dog</animal>
    <animal>aardvark</animal>
  </animals>
</configuration>
```

What expression use to get 'dog'. It should be something like `${configuration.animals.animal<?>}`.

Comment: did you try `${configuration.animals[1]}` ?

Comment: I found the feature request : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/PLXUTILS-37 marked as fixed, but according some comments it is not.

Comment: @ben75: `${configuration.animals[1]}` works fine, thanks. Despite the linked discussion it works both with `help:evaluate` and written in pom. I use Maven 3.0.5. Can you put it below as a regular answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `${configuration.animals[1]}`

Reference :  http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/PLXUTILS-37