# Maven: How to reference a developer's e-mail in POM file?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

As known, if I have attributes as such in a POM file:

```
<project ...>
    ...
    <groupId>com.bosch</groupId>
    <artifactId>jenkins-ci</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    ...
    <organization>
        <name>Organization Name</name>
    </organization>
    ...
</project>
```

... I can reference them with `${project.artifactId}`, `${project.organization.name}` and so on.

But how can I reference the ids or e-mails of developers within the tags below?

```
<project ...>
    ...
    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>dev1</id>
            <name>Developer 1</name>
            <email>developer1@email.com</email>
        </developer>
        <developer>
            <id>dev2</id>
            <name>Developer 2</name>
            <email>developer2@email.com</email>
        </developer>
    </developers>
    ...
</project>
```

**EDIT:** The answer from *@P-a Bäckström* seems the correct one, but for me it works only when I use `help:evaluate`.

Taking the following example:

```
<project
    ...
    <properties>
        <testId>${project.developers[0].id}</testId>
    </properties>
    ...
    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>dev1</id>
            <name>Developer 1</name>
            <email>developer1@email.com</email>
        </developer>
        <developer>
            <id>dev2</id>
            <name>Developer 2</name>
            <email>developer2@email.com</email>
        </developer>
    </developers>
    ...
    <organization>
        <name>${project.developers[0].id}</name>
    </organization>
    ...
</project>
```

Then the following works...

```
C:\workspaces\rafael_workspace\jenkins-parent-pom>mvn help:evaluate
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Jenkins POM 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate (default-cli) @ jenkins-ci ---
[INFO] No artifact parameter specified, using 'com.test:jenkins-ci:pom:0.0.1' as project.
[INFO] Enter the Maven expression i.e. ${project.groupId} or 0 to exit?:
${project.developers[0].id}
[INFO]
dev1
[INFO] Enter the Maven expression i.e. ${project.groupId} or 0 to exit?:
${testId}
[INFO]
dev1
[INFO] Enter the Maven expression i.e. ${project.groupId} or 0 to exit?:
${project.organization.name}
[INFO]
dev1
```

However, when I use `C:\workspaces\rafael_workspace\jenkins-parent-pom>mvn help:effective-pom` to resolve the effective POM, those references are unchanged. The effective POM still shows me the `${project.developers[0].id}` instead of the actual value `dev1`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Addressing list items in maven expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514381/addressing-list-items-in-maven-expressions)

Comment: @Joe, I agree it's duplicated. Maybe I didn't search with the right keywords before...

Comment: Please show the example where you are trying to use those id's and how you a trying to do it?

Comment: @khmarbaise I added the use case to my question. I'm adding this comment because I don't if you received a notification when I edited my post.

Answer (score 6):

You might need to upgrade Maven, but this is supposed to work:

```
${project.developers[0].id}
```

Comment: It seems to be the right answer! But so far I'm only able to do so using `mvn help:evaluate`. When I check the effective POM, however, the attributes are not being replaced. I've tried with the latest version of Maven as well. I'll select your answer as soon as I identify what is the stup!d mistake I'm making...